# Promise.all() doesn't work after a previous promise in a co() function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The code below works properly:

```
"use strict"

const request = require('request-promise-native')
const co = require('co')

function getResults() {
    return co(function *() {
        //yield request('http://www.google.es').then(res => {
        //    console.log('Request 1')
        //})
        const paginatedResources = [
            'http://www.yahoo.com',
            'http://www.gmail.com'
        ]
        const promises = []
        paginatedResources.forEach((uri) => {
            promises.push(request(uri))
        })
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(res) {
            console.log('Request 2 and 3') //Order doesn't matters
        })
    })
}

getResults()
```

Promise.all() returns expected values, but if I uncomment line 8 (**yield...**), Promise.all seems unresolved (console log 2 and 3 message doesn't appear).  Why the resolve of the first promise is affecting the second one?

Comment: Seen as `co` was mainly a stepping stone to async / await.  Now async/await is here, any reason your not using them instead.

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough details. What does 'unresolved' mean? Is the promise that is returned from co() rejected? Is it pending? There is no evidence that the first promise resolves. Why should the second one resolve if the first doesn't?  Please, provide all necessary details, including https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: As I understand it, async/await was introduce in ES2017 (ES8). This project is based on ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in code. It works properly. I found the error in test suite used to test the code with Mocha and 'chai-as-promised'. I had a line like this:

```
expect(getResults()).should.eventually.equal("foo")
```

But this result should be returned to await the response:

```
return expect(getResults()).should.eventually.equal("foo")
```

Adding return statement the test works.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning anything:

```
return co(function *() {
  //let firstPageResponse = yield request(getListConfiguredResource(filterBy)).then((res) => { return res })
  //let paginatedResources = getAllPaginatedResources(firstPageResponse.headers)
  let paginatedResources = [
      'https://api.github.com/users/jvcalderon/gists?per_page=100&page=1',
      'https://api.github.com/users/jvcalderon/gists?per_page=100&page=2',
      'https://api.github.com/users/jvcalderon/gists?per_page=100&page=3'
  ];
  //here you should return something
  return Promise.all(
    paginatedResources.map(
      url => request(getBaseConfiguredResource(url))
    )
  );
})
```

If you want an iterator that pre fetches all resources you cannot return a resolve value because you don't know when the consumer is going to call `next()` and if any of the asynch processing is done when the consumer does. So the consumer has to handle a promise:

```
/*
causes a promise returning function not to be called
untill less than max are active
usage example:
max2 = throttle(2);
functions = [fn1,fn2,fn3...fn100];//functions returning promise
params = [param1,param2,param3...param100]
Promise.all(//even though a 100 promises are created, only 2 are active
  functions.map(
    (fn,index)=>
      max2(fn)(params[index])
      .then(...)
  )
)
*/
const throttle =
  (max) =>{
    var que = [];
    var running = 0;
    const wait = function*(resolve,fn,arg){
      return resolve(fn(arg));
    };
    const nextInQue = ()=>{
      const it = que[0];
      que=que.slice(1);
      if(it){
        it.next();
      }
      return true;
    };
    const queItem = (fn,arg)=>
      new Promise(
        (resolve,reject)=>que.push(wait(resolve,fn,arg))
      )
    ;
    return (fn)=>(arg)=>{
      const p = queItem(fn,arg)
        .then(x=>nextInQue() && x)
      ;
      running++;
      if(running<=max){
        nextInQue();
      }
      return p;
    };    
  }
;

/*
result.toPromse(result) 
  if result is type Error a rejected promise is returned
    reject reason is result.val
  if result is of type Value a resolved promise is returned
    resolve is result.val
  else a resolved promise is returned
    resolve value is result
result toResult
  if promise is rejected the rejection is caught
    the promise resolves to a result of type Error
    with val of reject reason
  if promise is resolved
    the promise resolves to a result of type Value
    with val of resolved value
*/
const result = (function(){
  const Error = function(val){this.val=val;}
  const Value = function(val){this.val=val;}
  return {
    toResult:promise =>
      promise.then(
        val => new Value(val)
        ,reject => new Error(reject)
      )
    //a promise resolving in a result (Error or Value)
    ,toPromise:result =>
      result.then(
        x => 
          (x.constructor === Error)
            ?Promise.reject(x.val)
            :(x.constructor === Value)
              ?Promise.resolve(x.val)
              :Promise.resolve(x)
      )
  }
})();

const test = function *() {
  var i = -1;
  //maximal 2 unresolved promises
  const max2 = throttle(2);
  const paginatedResources = [
    '/index.html',
    //causes fetch to return a rejected promise
    'http://ldsjdslfjalksfljasdflkjasdflkjsdljla/error',
    '/index.html'
  ];
  //pre fetch all resources
  const promises = 
    paginatedResources
      .map(
        url =>
          //toResult causes any promise to resolve in a result
          result.toResult(//max2(fetch)(url) gets uncaught in promise
            max2(//maximal 2 active request (can change throttle)
              fetch
            )(url)
          ) 
      )
  ;
  while(++i<promises.length){
    yield promises[i];
  }
}

//consuming the itirator
const it = test();
const consumeNext = () =>{
  var v;
  return (v = it.next()).done
    ?Promise.resolve("we are done")
    //toPromise causes result type to convert in promise
    // that is resolved or rejected based on result
    // being Value or Error
    :result.toPromise(v.value).then(x=>x.text())
}
consumeNext()
  .then(
    x=>console.log("first resouce:",x.length)
    ,reject=>console.warn(reject)
  )
;
consumeNext()
  .then(
    x=>console.log("second resouce:",x.length)
    ,reject=>console.warn(reject)
  )
;
consumeNext()
  .then(
    x=>console.log("third resouce:",x.length)
    ,reject=>console.warn(reject)
  )
;
```

Comment: Don't do that "pre-fetching". Creating the promises without immediately yielding and awaiting them will lead to unhandled rejections if there is an error.

Comment: @Bergi Are you saying that creating an iterator of promises will result in silent errors? I know that my consumeNext function and the way I call consumeNext does not have a reject handler,  so I added one in the update.

Comment: Nothing specifically about the iterator, but creating promises and then waiting before only later calling `then` on them does result in *loud* `unhandledrejection` errors. And that's what happens in your `for (promise of paginatedResources.map(fetch)) yield promise` and `consumeNext` pattern.

Comment: @Bergi I see, when the fetch fails the browser thins I didn't handle the error because at time there is no `then(undefined,rejectHandler)`. I know Chrome start shouting at you in the console when that happens. A solution could be handling the reject in the test function and return a special value such as railway orientated programming in F#. I don't have time right now but will try and update tomorrow. Thank you for your input.

Comment: The proper (and simple) solution is just to use `Promise.all` like you did in your first snippet

Comment: @Bergi I agree, the op did not specify if the array of urls would be very large. If this app is a node application it can be hundreds, even a client app that stores results could have a large url array. Promise.all will slow down to the slowest response. Having potentially a lot urls to prefetch causes another problem; your app behaving badly so I added a throttle from my library functions. Wrapping fetch in `result.toResult` will catch rejected promises and rethrow them with `result.toPromise`.